# How to reference the modal that spawned a new modal - in jquery with Bootstrap modals

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to find the correct syntax to reference the (opener) modal which spawned a new modal.

I have about twelve modals setup in my html each with unique ids. The opening and closing of each, whether nested or not is working very well.

What i'm doing is catching the 'hidden' `bs.modal` event of the top (recently opened) modal then in that event i want to reference the id of the modal that spawned it.
Similar to window.open() - is there a modal.opener() that can get me the id of the opener modal. Since all modals are actually part of the same page i'm assuming the id of the required modal is the way to go???

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help you:

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  console.log(e.relatedTarget);
});
```

You can retrieve the button that fired event, and deal with it...

Comment: didnt work. I think the modals are parallel even though we assume them nested when you view the html of parent and nested modals the inner-most modal is not inside the parent but adjacent. Ill keep experimenting
cheers

Comment: With the code I sent, you can get the element that called the original event.
Can you please share more details of your code? Make a codepen / jsfiddle with it? Or edit your question and make a snippet code